# Data could not be load on grid using Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I created a stored procedure for selecting department information from `department` table, and call it from C#, but the data is not loaded in the data grid view.

This procedure version of Oracle 11G, and this is my SQL code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_SELECT_DEPARTMENT as c1
  SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN 
    OPEN c1 FOR 
        SELECT DEPARTEMENTID, DEPARTMENTNAME
        FROM TABLEDEPARTMENT; 
END;
```

And here is my C# code:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString());

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("PPROCEDURE_SELECT_DEPARTMENT", con);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

When I load my grid, the data does not appear.

Comment: `OracleCommand("PPROCEDURE_SELECT_DEPARTMENT", con);`...is that a typo? You have misspelled the procedure name. (You have a double "P" in case it's not as obvious as I thought.)

Comment: i have type many type of name such as proc1, selectproc etc but same problem found ,

Answer (score 2):

you have the procedure defined incorrectly, although it's syntax is valid. As it stands the variable c1 is local to the procedure. The cursor is opened but then nothing is done with it. You need to define c1 as an out parameter of the procedure.

```
create or replace procedure 
procedure_select_department(c1 out sys_refcursor)
as  
begin 
    open c1 for 
        select departementid, departmentname
        from tabledepartment; 
end;
```

This will now return the cursor to your program. Unfortunately, I have little understanding of c# and don't know how you'll need to modify the statement to call the procedure.